# Ansible lineinfile won't add at end of file if line is already present somewhere

Tags: ansible

The code:

```
- name: Mark ending
  delegate_to: localhost
  lineinfile:
    create: yes
    insertafter: 'EOF'
    path: '{{ output_file }}'
    line: '=================='
```

Ansible version 2.8.6

This line is only added the first time the command is executed. I would expect it to add it every time.

The documentation recommends `insertafter: 'EOF'` for inserting lines at the end of a file, so that's what I'm using.

But now it seems to ignore every insert of this after the first.

More is inserted in between. I'm just using this command to indicate a particular thing has passed.

Setting `validate: ''` Changes nothing. How do I fix this?

Comment: `This line is only added the first time the command is executed` => this is absolutely what is expected with your actual task. If the line does not exists it will be inserted after EOF. If it already exists (anywhere in the file) nothing will happen and ansible will report 'OK'. You can try to use `regexp` in place of `insertafter` to verify a specific line exists at end of file and insert it if different from the one you expect. You could even try to only match end of file and replace it with your line unconditionally but that won't be idempotent.

Comment: @Zeitounator Really? So, if I want to output a bunch of stuff to a single file, the same file at each step of my process, `lineinfile` is not the correct command to use? Which command would be?

Comment: The typical use case of `lineinfile` is to make sure a specific line is present in a config file. What you describe looks like logging. If you have a different line each time (and it does not exists from a previous run), `lineinfile` can do the trick. If not you have other options like (absolutely not exhaustive) [logging the full play to a file](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/callback/log_plays.html), configuring logging in ansible.cfg, using `command` to append to a file, creating your own module to log, using tricked `lineinfile`  (i.e. replace EOF with line)...